# Getting certificate error even after importing the certificate to Glassfish

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish

I am using LDAPS server to connect from JAVA with Glassfish server.I am getting error.
**401: simple bind failed: msp.amadeus.net:636; nested exception is

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: 
msp.amadeus.net:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target].**
```

I got the LDAPS server certifcate using command s_client  -connect msp.amadeus.net:636. I saved it in test.cert file and imported to my glassfish server using command

`keytool -import -alias topodb`

`-keystore /tools/var/domains/aco/config/cacerts.jks -file /tmp/topodb.cert`

I restarted the server but still I am getting the same exception.
Can you please tell whet is going wrong?